# Ubuntu Installation issue Gigabyte z68xp-ud4 with a gtx780OC

Tags: system-installation

I want to dual boot my windows 7 desktop pc with ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04 so that I can run openFOAM CFD software. I have tried with a cd but no luck, the install just doesn't progress. the purple screen comes up, then disappears, some text appears on screen and then an underscore in the top left corner just starts flashing...nothing else happens.

Gigabyte's website says "Due to different Linux support condition provided by chipset vendors, please download Linux driver from chipset vendors' website or 3rd party website."

I'm stuck as I don't know which ones/haven't been able to find the drivers I need. I am very new to ubuntu and I'm not sure where to start. I have been having a lot of trouble installing ubuntu.

Here are my system specifications.

- Motherboard: Gigabyte z68xp-ud4 (rev1.3) (z68 express chipset)
- GPU: Gigabyte GTX780OC
- SSD: Intel 520 256GB (40GB to be partitioned for linux)
- RAM: Corsair vengeance low profile (16GB, 4x2GB, 1600Mhz)
- CPU: Intel Core i7 2600k

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Karel. Unfortunately I have not been able to find anything in the forums regarding an SSD or anything about running ubuntu with this board. This board should support ubuntu since gigabyte themselves say so. What settings in the BIOS would have to be changed? Some people say it may be my GPU? I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: My mistake I meant DVD. Thanks for the tips, I'll give it a go. Lets see what happens.

Comment: Also people have told me that using a USB to install ubuntu might be a better option?  Is that true?

Comment: ok so I've been doing a bit of reading over the last day or so. I have a feeling my GPU driver could also be a reason why the UI for the installation wasn't loading. So before I change try any BIOS changes, I was thinking I'll try plug my monitor in using the onboard graphics to see if it lets me install Linux using a bootable USB I've made. Then hopefully I'll be able to download and install the nvidia driver for the gtx780 through Linux. I hope that is the issue. What are your thoughts on this plan? I'll be back here if it doesn't work out though haha

Comment: Awesome I'll have a look at the software center once it installs (hopefully). Also I've been watching a few installation videos on youtube and I have a question. I've already made a partition on my SSD in windows. When I go through the installation, when I select install alongside windows 7 should my partition (unallocated space) automatically be detected and selected? Or do I have to initialise the drive in windows and manually select that during the install?

Comment: Hmmm I've run into an odd problem. For some reason the BIOS screen isn't showing on my monitor when I run my monitor cable straight to the hdmi (using dvi-hdmi adapter) on the motherboard. As in its a black screen. when I put the dvi cable back into my gpu it displays straight away...Do you think I need to completely remove the GPU from the system? I would have thought that the GPU would not be used if the monitor was plugged directly to the motherboard. Its annoying because without the BIOS I can't change the boot order.

Comment: No Problem, If I feel there are still things that are needed once this is solved, I'll comment there.

I have just tried using a usb. It is looking more promising. The screen which gives the option to install ubuntu came up for the first time. However when I selected install, I got a brief flash of the UI and then in went black with a pointer in the centre and I couldn't do anything after that. But this is still a huge step forward (it loaded). What do you suggest is the best way forward. I have seen some posts about nomodeset but I don't understand what it does. I think we are getting closer.

Comment: This is the thread I read: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

My screen was black but with a white pointer in the middle. I'm not sure if its the same issue but it may be.

Comment: How does partitioning the hard drive work through that UI?